# Handle Pinch, Zoom, Rotate Gestures in WinRT App

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

I can handle 1-finger `Tapped`, `DoubleTapped` and `Holding` gestures by using the control's specific events and 1-finger swipe gestures using `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationStarted` events.

But I don't know how to handle pinch, zoom and rotate gestures. Can anyone elaborate on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManipulationDelta event gives you args.Delta.Scale/Rotation values assuming your ManipulationMode property set like

```
ManipulationMode =
    ManipulationModes.TranslateX |
    ManipulationModes.TranslateY |
    ManipulationModes.Rotate |
    ManipulationModes.Scale |
    ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia;
```

(or  some such).